# does task scheduler executes scripts before system boot in redhat

Tags: linux, redhat, boot, ntfs

i'm trying to mount ntfs partition in redhat at startup i wrote shell script at put it in task scheduler to start at bootup, but unfortunately redhat is mounted on my one ntfs partion.....so it gives fs not found error at startup........
can anyone tell me how can i delete script using grub command line or any live linux.

http://cradingz.wordpress.com/2012/07/03/shell-script-boot-ntfs-partitions-on-startup/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell script to Mount all ntfs partitions was executing before root file System is mounted, So this caused problem that Bootloader couldn't find Root file system as the drive was mounted Somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make these dirs right now and make /etc/fstab settings to mount these partitions there. /etc/fstab is a standard way to mount fs's at startup. 
I suppose you don't need no scripts for so pretty common task.
Look at `man fstab`

Comment: in redhat linux using ntfs-3g we can mount ntfs fs.so rather mounting ntfs partitions every time i used shell-script.but redhat was installed in free space created by one of those ntfs partition.so whenever i'm booting redhat it doesnt start but gives error that fs not found

Comment: Seems like i've got your point. So, red hat installed on a ntfs part and tries to mount it onto root fs? That's terrible if this is what is really happened.

Comment: problem solved,before booting fs was mounted in another directory so bootloader couldn't find fs